# Sum Case when Sql

Tags: sql

```
account_id  revenue_2017    revenue_2018    acct_rev_growth
INTEGER        DECIMAL         DECIMAL               DECIMAL
e.g. 123455  e.g. 1000.00   e.g. 1300.00    e.g. 0.30

account_id   team          region
INTEGER     VARCHAR (25)     VARCHAR (25)
e.g 46567   e.g Tech    e.g. NAMER-US
```

In one row for each region, show the region, its Tech team (team = ‘Tech’) revenue for 2018 and its Edu team (team = ‘Edu’) revenue for 2018.

Answer (score 1):

To get each region and each team, group the records into both fields and then calculate the sum of each group.

```
select sum(table1.revenue_2018) as sum_2018
from table1 
join table2 on table1.account_id = table2.account_id 
group by table2.region, table2.team
```